# Using Regular expression to match Multiple choice?

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

How can I extract multiple choice question from a text document. Each Question start with a number and dot

```
1. Any Text _____ Goes here, And end with ? Or . And also can contain another paragraph.
a) possible
b) use regex
c) not possible
d) I dont know

Ans: b
```

Above is the example how a questions look like. The text file include some fill in blanks and some essay writing stuff but I only want multiple choice questions part Until `Ans:...`. All questions will have answers a, b, c, and d.

I copied my text in Dreamweaver so that I can use regular expression.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"1. Any Text _ Goes here, And end with ? Or ."

can translate to this in regex:

```
    \d+\.[^\?\.]*[\?\.]
```

[image: Regular expression image]

Does that work for you? This assumes you never have any question marks or periods within the question until the end... but that's sort of what you implied as well.

Edit: Since you want the answers and not just the question itself and you are looking to distinguish between other types of questions, try this:

```
([ \t]*\d+\.[^\n]+\n(?:[ \t]*[a-zA-Z]\)[^\n]+\n)+[\s]*Ans:[^\n]*)
```

[image: Regular expression image]

[Edit live on Debuggex](http://www.debuggex.com/r/iqGNw0FMGjbPG4kw)

Comment: Thank you very much for reply, and what about the middle part a)...b)...c)...d)... And Ans:..

Comment: How can you draw the stat diagram like this?

Comment: The problem with this is if yo add a random text between two question it will also select the random text.

Comment: This one also select the question that are lets say fill in the blanks. is it possible to restrict that question must have options like a)... b)... c)... d)...

Comment: Ah, I didn't how specific you wanted it and what other possibilites are.. I'll update

Comment: Yes its always a) ..\n b) ..\n c) ..\n d) ..\n

Comment: Yes i've tested it i think its still not working. please take a look.http://www.debuggex.com/r/gnvlXvJcJ0qOhB-Y/0

Answer (score 0):

## Description

This expression will:

- capture the entire question thru to the answer into Group 0
- capture the question number into Group 1
- capture the text of the question into Group 2
- capture the block of possible answers to Group 3
- capture the answer value to Group 4
- allow all punctuation including question marks

`^(\d+)\.\s*(.*?)[\r\n\s]+(^a\).*?)[\r\n\s]+Ans:\s+([a-z]+\b)`

[image]

## Example

See here for working example: http://www.rubular.com/r/RQoobTedtg

**Sample Text**

```
12. Any Text _ Goes here, And end with ? Or . And also can contain another paragraph.
a) Q1 possible
b) Q1 use regex
c) Q1 not possible
d) Q1 i dont know

Ans: a

Do you like kittens or other random text?

24. Second question is here
a) Q2 possible
b) Q2 use regex
c) Q2 not possible
d) Q2 i dont know

Ans: b
```

**Matches**

```
Match 1
1.  12
2.  Any Text _ Goes here, And end with ? Or . And also can contain another paragraph.
3.  a) Q1 possible
    b) Q1 use regex
    c) Q1 not possible
    d) Q1 i dont know
4.  a

Match 2
1.  24
2.  Second question is here
3.  a) Q2 possible
    b) Q2 use regex
    c) Q2 not possible
    d) Q2 i dont know
4.  b
```

## Notes

This regex does assume that each question will have an `Ans: x` at the end.