# Regular Expresssion to find multiple choice questions (inlcuding newlines)

Tags: c#, regex

I'm trying to find a regex to match the questions in a PDF textbook. The questions take the following structure:

```
1. What does cabotage refer to?
a. Domestic air services within a state
b. An international air carrier
c. A flight above territorial waters
d. Crop spraying
2. The Convention signed by the states relating to damage caused by foreign aircraft 
to persons and property on the ground is:
a. the Tokyo convention
b. the Rome convention
c. the Warsaw convention
d. the Paris convention.
```

I've tried modifying the one given here [Using Regular expression to match Multiple choice?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17351337/using-regular-expression-to-match-multiple-choice) but I cannot get it to work across the newline character. Closest I got was `\(\d+\.[^\n+]+\n(?:[ \t]*[a-zA-Z]\.[^\n]+\n)+[\s]*)\` which works but not for multi-line questions.

Comment: Try `(?sm)^\d.*?(?=^\s*a\.)`

Comment: Maybe `(\d+\.(?:(?!^[a-zA-Z]\.)[\S\s])+\n(?:[ \t]*[a-zA-Z]\.[^\n]+\n)+)` would be a good start? See: https://regex101.com/r/4XXKWq/1

Comment: You can match optional lines after it that do not start with digits or a char and a dot `\d+\..+(?:\n(?![ \t]*(?:[a-z]|\d+)\.).*)*(?:\n[ \t]*[a-zA-Z]\..*)*` https://regex101.com/r/wI0uWA/1

Comment: Thank you. @Thefourthbird Yours works the best.

Comment: Thanks @41686d6564standsw.Palestine yours works great too.

Comment: ive added the full PDF, there are some erroneous matches. https://regex101.com/r/voK4ay/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not matching the second block because your pattern (note that in the question there is a typo) does not allow the lines in the repeating part to start with something else than: `[ \t]*[a-zA-Z]\.`

After matching the lines that start with the digits and the dot, you can optionally match all lines that do not start with a pattern for the question or a multiple choice answer.

Then you can repeat 1 more times matching a multiple choice answer starting with a char a-z and a dot.

```
\d+\..+(?:\n(?![ \t]*(?:[a-z]|\d+)\.).*)*(?:\n[ \t]*[a-zA-Z]\..*)+
```

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/L4EOJG/1)

Some notes

- You can also match a newline with `\r?\n`
- If you mean to match the whole line char without newlines and at least a single char, you can write `.+` instead of `[^\n+]+`
- To match a space without a newline in C# you can write `[\p{Zs}\t]`

See a [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/5Qq2pj/1) for the longer pattern for the example pdf in the comments:

Comment: Thankyou for your answer. It does not work for triple line questions see extended question bank. Also, what typo?

Comment: @GeorgeGohl The pattern by itself now is not valid, see https://regex101.com/r/Zx54ik/1

Comment: @GeorgeGohl Do you mean like this? https://regex101.com/r/7roluj/1

Comment: https://regex101.com/r/cCxUPs/1

Comment: @GeorgeGohl https://regex101.com/r/m7waFn/1

Comment: thankyou for your help @thefourthbird. It mathes parts of the contents and extra non-questions. See https://regex101.com/r/oSM8eA/1 for full pdf text.

Comment: @GeorgeGohl Are there any more rules to it that the lines can or can not have between the question and the multiple choice answers to constrain the matches?

Comment: Im not sure, its just a PDF read into plaintext. The answers and questions are often un multiple lines. There are always 4 possible answers.

Comment: @GeorgeGohl Perhaps this will have a better matching https://regex101.com/r/E4prAe/1

Comment: @GeorgeGohl There is a lot of noise in the document, and for some entries the digits and dot or the character a,b,c,d followed by a dot are not consistent https://regex101.com/r/EaDrVr/1

Comment: That works a treat, You're a Regex genius!

Comment: 1. When, in airspace where VFR is permitted, the PIC of an IFR flight wishes to 
continue the flight in accordance with VFR until destination:
1. the pilot must inform the control unit of his intention using the expression 
“cancelling my IFR flight”.
2. the pilot must request and obtain clearance to continue under VFR.
3. the pilot must communicate the necessary changes to the current flight plan.
4. the flight plan automatically becomes a VFR flight.
Which of the following combinations is correct?
a. 2 and 3. 
b. 2 and 4. 
c. 1 and 3. 
d. 1 and 4.

Comment: Alas, the exception to the rule, would this be too complex to add in?

Comment: This is a very robust regex

Answer (score 2):

Try the following -

```
/(\d+\.)((.*\n)(?!\d+\.).*)*/g
```

It matched as follows -
[image]

Comment: Thank you. It seems too vauge for the full PDF, see https://regex101.com/r/jErc50/1

Comment: @GeorgeGohl The full pdf text contains lots of noisy text. You will have to drop the noisy text somehow. My approach was as follows - 
- Start by digit-with-a-dot
- Any text along with the next lines
- Should stop when there is another occurrence of digit-with-a-dot in the next line.

Comment: See filtered plaintext - https://regex101.com/r/jwLLfq/1

Answer (score 1):

I assume a question ends with either a question mark `?` or a colon `:`.

Then you can use this regex:

```
^\d+\.[^:?]+[:?]\r?\n

new Regex(@"^\d+\.[^:?]+[:?]\r?\n", RegexOptions.Multiline);
```

**Explanation**:

`^` - match from start of a line

`\d+\.` - match one or more digits followed by a dot `.`

`[^:?]+` - match one or more characters not being colon `:`or question mark `?`

`[:?]\r?\n` - match a colon `:` or question mark `?` followed by newline.

Comment: Thankyou for your solution. Ive added the full PDF Here: https://regex101.com/r/voK4ay/1. There are some incorrect matches. Would it be possible to match the answers too ?

Comment: I give up - the real text does not follow any rules.

Comment: This a a processed version of the PDS. I filted on pages that contain the word "Questions" more than once.